# Passportjs Authentication password only

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I can't solve this one by myself / by reading the documentation:

I'd like to use PassportJS in my Express Nodejs application to implement password-only authentication in my website. But it seems like I don't understand PassportJS good enough.

My experience with PassportJS so far is, that I have a POST-Route to which I add the Local Strategy which works completely fine for me

```
var user = {
  password: "123"
};

passport.use('login', new passportLocal({
  passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
  if(password==="123"){
    return done(null, user);
  }else{
    return done(null, false);
  }
}));
```

If I understand this correctly; the HTML-Form values of "username" and "password" end up in the function-expression parameters `username` and `password` above

But how would I be able to pass the password from the URL as parameter instead of the HTML-Form value?

Like `req.params.password`

in

```
router.get('/:password', function(req,res,next){
});
```

I really hope someone understands what I am trying to express :P

Comment: Sounds like a really bad thing to be doing at all, which is likely why they don't support it out of the box.

Comment: `how would I be able to pass the password from the URL`  are you being serious? The point of passwords is that _you shouldn't be able too see them in clear text_!

Comment: I am completely aware, that what I am about to implement isn't secure. But firstly I didn't ask for your opinion about this. And secondly: I just want to implement this to add a minimal barrier which has to be passed to see the content of my website.